# Audio Library C++ for a multicross platform use (iphone, android...)

Tags: iphone, c++, android, audio, multiplatform

i'm trying to make a C++ engine that will read a mp3 file, and make some image zoom/translation depending on the time of the reading sound file. I think I could use OpenGL ES to render what I want, and calling some OpenGL ES instructions in my C++ files, and init my  drawing context in Obj-C/Java. I want to do the same for the sound, but i don't really know what to use, and if I can really do it or not in C++.

I searched for library so I found Bass and Fmod (which is not free for commercial use). They said it's multicross platform (Windows, Unix, MacOS) but I dont understand if it manners for mobile, and if I can really use it. Does anyone have been through this? Do you recommand me another free library?

Thanks again, and I apologize for my poor english,

Arnaud

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at libpd (Pure Data for embedded applications)

http://download.puredata.info/libpd (the library has been released very recently, but the code is very mature indeed)

http://createdigitalmusic.com/2010/10/libpd-put-pure-data-in-your-app-on-an-iphone-or-android-and-everywhere-free/

Answer (score 1):

Audio is often problematic and it is pretty much always a good idea to write your own high-level API that does exactly what you want to do (and nothing else) and to assume you will then be writing a thin layer between it and whatever audio library you are using underneath. If you're lucky and there's a library available that does things the way you would do them then it's trivial. If not, at least it's still possible. In either case, your app code is not tied to an external sound API.

I have used FMOD on multiple different commercial projects over the years for PC, Mac and iPhone, and have always liked it - but it's not free. OpenAL has always seemed sorta, I dunno: clunky? But you only have to deal with it when writing your API layer, and your app code never has to see it.

It's easy for me to say "write your own API" since I've been writing commercial games for 20 years and so know what I think an audio API should look like. If you don't have your own idea how you think it should be, then I suggest you look at a 3rd party library that makes sense to you and take the functions from it that you will be using and write your own API to do be a set of functions that do nothing but call those.

Since you have both OpenAL and FMOD available to you free for development you can then make your API work with both, and chances are it's then going to work with anything else you might come across.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAL may be your best bet. Look at this answer: [Android OpenAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587295/android-openal/4464717#4464717)

It seems possible to compile OpenAL on Android.

Comment: From recent experience, OpenAL on *Symbian* is a pain and ultimately we abandoned it. I realise this isn't mentioned directly in the question, but for a cross platform library, check this out before going for OpenAL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for just PCM audio input/output ( and not MP3 decoding ) try PortAudio or RTAudio
[RtAudio or PortAudio, which one to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174393/rtaudio-or-portaudio-which-one-to-use)